# PHP case switch behaviour breaks a recursive scandir function

Tags: php, switch-statement

during my quest for some basic php knowledge , I tried to do a simple function to read files and dirs that will not use recursive iterators. (more of an exercise but actually needed for any php<5.3 servers)

the function works great - but when i tried to add a `switch` ($output) - it no longer lists all the files (for example, before adding the switch, it can see 61 files in 4 folders (3+root) but with the added `switch` it can only see 47 (only root) . 
am I doing something wrong here ? why does the `switch` statement break the faux "recursive-nest" ??

```
    function o99_list_my_files_scandir($dir,$output) 
    { 

        $result = $result2 = array(); 

        $root = scandir($dir); 

        foreach($root as $value) 
        { 

          if($value === '.' || $value === '..' || $value == 'Thumb.db' || $value == 'Thumbs.db' || $value == '') { continue;} 

            if(is_file("$dir/$value")) {$result[]="$dir/$value"; continue;} // array files
            if(is_dir("$dir/$value")) {$result2[]="$dir/$value"; continue;} // array dirs

            foreach(o99_list_my_files_scandir("$dir/$value") as $value) 

            { 
                $result[] = $value; 
            }
        } 
            // this is the troublemaker ...

            switch ($output) {
                case 'dirs' :
                return array_filter($result2);  // clean empty results of dirs
                break;

                case 'files' :
                return array_filter($result);   // Clean empty array of files
                break; 
            }

}
```

is there any other simple way to get the function to return separate lists of dirs AND files and not a unified array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in this line...

```
foreach(o99_list_my_files_scandir("$dir/$value") as $value)
```

...you don't give `$output` to the recursively called function, so it won't output anything. Change it to:

```
foreach(o99_list_my_files_scandir("$dir/$value", $output) as $value)
```

Actually you should have gotten a warning about the missing argument.

Comment: Thanks -  point in the right direction. it actually did not work at first , but it DID work when i removed the `continue;` from  `if(is_dir("$dir/$value")) {$result2[]="$dir/$value"; continue;} // array dirs` .. - would be nice to understand why ..

Comment: Because with the `continue`s the recursion is never executed - one of the `continue`s will always be triggered and skip over it. If it's a regular file the upper one and if it's a directory the lower one (which you must remove to make it work).

Answer (score 1):

You do not seem to set `$output` anywhere.

BTW: For learning purposes I strongly recommend adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` as very first line of your script and re-run (first, without fixing anything), because you should have seen a warning as 2nd function parameter is not optional. You got signature

```
function o99_list_my_files_scandir($dir,$output)
```

but call

```
o99_list_my_files_scandir("$dir/$value")
```

while you should

```
o99_list_my_files_scandir("$dir/$value", $output)
```

in your `foreach()`

Comment: $output is a function parameter

Comment: +1 thanks ! see the comment on @AndreKR reply . unfortunately I can only accept one ..